# Unable to catch the error using try..catch in powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to catch the error if DL is not found. I have written the below code

```
try
{
    Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "#AB-TestDL"|select ManagedBy -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
     if($Error[0] -match "couldn't be found on")
     {
        Write-Host "DL not found"
     }
}
```

But when i run the code, it throws an error as "#AB-TestDL" couldn't be found on ...
Please help me capture this error. Thanks..

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that a `Select-Object` errors out. I'd recommend to move the `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Get-DistributionGroup`.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks...It worked,It means that we need to put -ErrorAction Stop at the end of script which can give error...Is there not any way where we can bind the whole statement with single -ErrorAction Stop

Comment: Please read [about_Preference_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter on the `Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "#AB-TestDL"` CmdLet instead of `Select-Object`.

`Select-Object` can be used to create a new object but it isn't a error for the CmdLet when a property does not exist.

```bsh
C:\> [PSCustomObject]@{ Test = 123 } | Select Test2 -ErrorAction Stop

Test2
-----
```

You can however make it work different (while i still suggest moving `-ErrorAction Stop` to the first CmdLet):

```bsh
Set-StrictMode -Version 3

$Object = [PSCustomObject] @{
    Test = 123
}

try {
    $null = $Object.Test2
} catch {
    throw "I don't extist and catch because of strictmode version 3"
}
```

Just an idea which came into my head. I actually never used strictmode this way.